# Find key in hash table (ContainsKey) not working

Tags: powershell

I'm loading a hash table with this:

```
$htA = dir | Where-Object {$_.Name -match "\.output\.[A-Z]-[0-9]\.csv"} | select name,length
```

When I try to search the Key column like thusly:

```
$htA.ContainsKey($h.name)
```

I get this super neat-o error:

Method invocation failed because **[Selected.System.IO.FileInfo] does not contain a method named 'ContainsKey'.**

```
At line:3 char:9
 IF ($htA.ContainsKey($h.name) -eq $false) {

     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (ContainsKey:String) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound**
```

So is this not a legit hashtable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$htA is created as the type cast to it, in this case System.IO.FileInfo. Try this:

```
$htA = @{} # Initialises as an empty hash table
foreach ($file in (dir | Where-Object {$_.Name -match "\.output\.[A-Z]-[0-9]\.csv"} | select name,length))
{
$htA.Add($file.name, $file.length) # Populate hash table
}
```